# Is it possible to give edit issue permission if there's not work log on issue in JIRA?

Tags: permissions, jira

I configured that jira-users group members can create issues.

And I want to give edit permission to jira-users but only if the issue hasnot a work log in it

Is this possible in JIRA 4.4.x

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you can only edit an issue if work hasn't started on it? Tricky. I think I'd end up editing system-issueoperations-plugin.xml and changing the condition elements to add a new condition. The new condition would be a custom condition that checked whether the issue has at least one work log.

Comment: But first I'd ask myself why I would want to do such an unusual thing.

Comment: sometimes jira-users can want to add new things to issue after the working of developers already got started to work on.I want to forbid jira-users to do this. Instead of this they can open new issues

Answer (score 0):

You can change issue permissions so that only assignee can edit this issue. So when developer starts work on the issue he assigns himself to this issue and only he can edit it.

Documentation is here - http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA044/Managing+Project+Permissions